# What happens to duplicate keys when using dictionaryWithObjects:forKeys:?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsdictionary

If I use `dictionaryWithObjects:forKeys:`, and my array of keys happens to have duplicates, what happens? I presume the last instance of the duplicate key will be the value associated with the key; is that correct?

Comment: Why don't you try and see? Debugger is your friend. To dump the contents of the dictionary, right-click on the variable and select "Print description".

Comment: Why don't you try it out and see what happens?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[The docs say](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000140-CBHDBBAJ):

> #### dictionaryWithObjects:forKeys:
>
> ...
>   This method steps through the `objects` and `keys` arrays, creating entries in the new dictionary as it goes.

Since a dictionary can't have multiple entries for the same key, yes, the "steps through" strongly implies that later elements in the initializing arrays will clobber earlier ones.